# Inheritance: How to make parent method work with other parent methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

So I have two classes, where one inherits from another and overrides all parent methods:

```py
class Parent:
    def name(self):
        return 'parent'

    def run(self):
        print(f'calling method from parent: I am {self.name()}')


class Child(Parent):
    def name(self):
        return 'child'

    def run(self):
        print(f'calling method from child: I am {self.name()}')
        return super().run()
```

Running the following piece `Child().run()` triggers method `run` both for child and parent, and the output is:

```
calling method from child: I am child
calling method from parent: I am child
```

And result is clear - since we have redefined method `name`, new version is used in both `run` methods. (`I am child` on both lines)
And that's the main problem - the way I want it to work is for parent `run` method to use parent `name`.

What I have accomplished so far is replacing `super` with `self.__class__.__mro__[1]`, so that method looks like

```py
def run(self):
    print(f'calling method from child: I am {self.name()}')
    return self.__class__.__mro__[1]().run()
```

The way it works is it gets parent class using method resolution order and creates instance of parent class. It works fine and now result is:

```
calling method from child: I am child
calling method from parent: I am parent
```

But I don't like this solution:

- Single inheritance - since we hardcode parent class index, we cannot make it work with several parent classes
- Using MRO doesn't feel right for this case
- Here we assume `__init__` doesn't take extra arguments

I think clue is in changing `self.name` in parent method so that it will use parent method explicitly, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the current class that the method is defined in by using `__class__`:

```py
class Parent:
    def name(self):
        return 'parent'

    def run(self):
        print(f'calling method from parent: I am {__class__.name(self)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making `name` a name-mangled (`__`) attribute that's private to the class:

```
class Parent:
    __name = 'parent'

    def run(self):
        print(f'calling method from parent: I am {self.__name}')


class Child(Parent):
    __name = 'child'

    def run(self):
        print(f'calling method from child: I am {self.__name}')
        return super().run()

Child().run()
# calling method from child: I am child
# calling method from parent: I am parent
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in my case. My example is simplified version of what I'm actually dealing with. In fact, method `text` accepts arguments and performs some actions, so we cannot replace it with class var. Although method `text` can be static method, if that helps.

Comment: You can do the same `__` trick with a method.  Is there any reason to use inheritance/overriding for these methods at all, rather than just giving them different names, i.e. any case where you'd want to call `Child.name` within the context of a `Parent` method?  If so it would be helpful to include that in your example.  Based on the simplified version it doesn't seem like you're getting any benefit from inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, there are nearly 5 classes (can be more in future) that inherit from each other and need to call their parent method. I'll try to come up with a better example soon